# django how to change database with click button on new window and close, refresh the main page?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms

I made 'alert list' page. (alert_list.html)

and when I click the button, it renders detail page uses pk on new window. (alert_detail.html)

And there is confirm button on alert_detail.html that change event.event_status value 1 to 0.

But , I have some problem with handle this.

The things what I want to do is..

1. change Event.event_status value to 0. by click the confirm button
2. close new window(detail page)
3. refresh main page(alert list page)

```
<alert_list.html>

{% for event_alert in event_list %}
                {% if event_alert.event_status == 1 %}
                <div class="col-1 red">
                    <div class="p-3 rounded-2" id="dash_board_patient_alert">
                        <a href="{% url 'Alert Detail' event_alert.event_id %}">{{event_alert.member_id}} {{event_alert.event_type}}</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
                {{event_alert_activate_count}}
                {{pink_block}}
                {% for _ in pink_block %}
                <div class="col-1 pink">
                    <div class="p-3 rounded-2" id="dash_board_patient_alert">
                        <a href="#"></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                {% endfor %}

<alert_detail.html>

            {% for event_alert in event_list %}
            <form method="POST" class="post-form" action ="{% url 'Alert Update' event_alert.pk %}">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form }}
            <button
                type="submit"
                class="btn btn-primary"
                id="patient_alert_result_confirm">
                Confirm
            </button>
            </form>
            {% endfor %}

<alert_update.html>
I don't have any idea.. help me this page
```

```
<views.py>

def alert_list(request):
Event.objects.order_by('-event_time')[:12]
    event_alert_activate_count = Event.objects.filter(event_status__startswith='1')[:12].count()
    pink_block = int(12)
    event_list = Event.objects.order_by('-event_time')

    context = {
               'event_alert_activate_count': event_alert_activate_count,
               'event_list' : event_list,
               'pink_block' : pink_block
               }

    return render(request, 'dashboard/alert_list.html', context)



def alertDetail(request,pk):
    event = get_object_or_404(Event, pk=pk)
    event_list = Event.objects.order_by('-event_time')[:1]

    context = {'event_list': event_list,
               'event' : event,}
    return render(request, 'dashboard/alert_detail.html', context)



def alertUpdate(request,pk):
    event = get_object_or_404(Event,pk=pk)
    event_list = Event.objects.order_by('-event_time')[:1]
    if request.POST :
        event_status_form = EventStatusForm(request.POST)
        if event_status_form.is_valid():
            change_event_status = 0
            event.event_status = change_event_status
            event_status_form.save()
            return HttpResponse('<script type="text/javascript">window.parent.location.href = "/";')
    else :
        form = EventStatusForm(request.POST)
    context = {'event_list': event_list,
               'event' : event,
               'form' : form,}
    return HttpResponse('<script type="text/javascript">window.parent.location.href = "/";')
```

```
<model.py>

class Event(models.Model):
    member_id = models.ForeignKey(Member, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column = 'member_id')
    event_type = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    room_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    heart_rate = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    breath_rate = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    event_status = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    event_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)
```

```
<forms.py>
class EventStatusForm(forms.Form):

    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields=('event_status',)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways to handle this.

1. Use a form in your details view with a hidden field and assign the confirmation button in your html the role of submit. When the form is submitted, handle the event value switch in your detail view and redirect to main page.
2. Define another view (e.g. set_event) and respective url. The confirmation button redirects to the new url passing required parameters along. Then handle event switch in your new view and redirect to main page. You will need to take care of permissions in your new view (check if user is allowed to take action).
3. Use AJAX to submit data and link confirmation button to main page.